# How to make copies of a customised Live USB stick?

Tags: live-usb

I have spent some time and effort customising a Live USB setup of Ubuntu 14.04. 
I want to make copies of this environment, before it gets corrupted (has happened once recently).
I don't want to image the entire drive because it is a 16GB drive with 2 partitions, only one has the Live environment.

Is this the best way to go about it?
Boot with live CD and copy entire partition containing the Live USB files (on the pendrive), and use dd to copy the boot sector?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, just image the partition containing the live system

When booting from CD, you could either use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org)